# ASP.NET - Omitting the question mark character

Tags: asp.net

I was wondering if it is possible to omit the question mark in the URL after the aspx page and still be able to parse characters in the URL.  For example, let's say I have this URL: http://localhost/?specialparam,story:extra. When I navigate to the page it displays correctly and I'm able to parse my specialparam and story parameter. Now if I enter in the URL by omitting the '?' character as http://localhost/specialparam,story:extra then I get the page not found error.

A little backgound on why I am doing it this way.  I want to be able to shorten the URL sort of how they do it on bit.ly but be able to pass some special parameters that my .aspx page can parse.

I understand that with the '?' character in the URL it will go to the default document specified in IIS. Can I get some suggetions on if this is even possible to remove the '?' character or if URL Rewriting will help.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

[MVC 3](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/13/announcing-release-of-asp-net-mvc-3-iis-express-sql-ce-4-web-farm-framework-orchard-webmatrix.aspx) would do just the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The `?` character designates the beginning of the query string, so you can hardly remove it if you want to keep using query strings.  On the other hand, if you *do* remove it, you can simply refer to `Request.PathInfo`, which will give you all the data after the filename, but before the query string.  For example:

> http://localhost/Default.aspx/Your/Path/Info

The path info is `/Your/Path/Info`.  However, you would be required to include the `.aspx` file since otherwise the server wouldn't be able to distinguish from a real file on the web server.

(Also, the `?` character has absolutely nothing to do with default documents in IIS)